# image convolution using an even-sized kernel

Tags: image-processing, convolution

I was wondering, when you convolve with a 2x2 kernel, where do you put the result of the operation ? With a symmetric mask the result is applied to the pixel corresponding to the center of the mask; so what happens when a mask doesn't have a center ? Besides, why would someone use an even sized kernel ?

Comment: Another possible use of a 2x2 kernel is to find all right-angles in a skeleton. In my case, this is useful for finding the smallest set of branchpoints in a loopy skeleton network. I found that convolution with cv2.filter2D (python) places the result in the lower-right pixel.

Comment: interesting @Jon, thanks for the input, will look into that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, but whichever approach you use you may get a 0.5 pixel shift in the resulting image. You can see why this might happen intuitively by considering your 2x2 example as 3x3 with zero padding, e.g.

```
 k00  k01   0
 k10  k11   0
  0    0    0
```

As for why you might want to use an even size - one application of convolution is cross-correlation (flipping one of the images changes convolution to correlation and *vice versa*). Cross-correlation has many uses, including template matching (finding a target image within a larger image), so if your template has an even size then the resulting convolution/correlation will also involve an even sized "kernel".

Comment: what approaches are applicable specifically, can you bring an example?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I was just expanding the answer to include an example.

Comment: interesting, so you choose  the center arbitrarily ? and when you do it, it remains the same  through all the convolution (correlation) process ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't really matter, apart from the resulting shift. BTW, another example to think about is bilinear interpolation - for this you have effectively a 2x2 kernel, where the coeffs are your interpolation factors.

Comment: @PaulR, actually it does matter. If you put the results pixel in the upper left hand corner, you can perform the convolution with a simple scanline operation in the same memory footprint.

Comment: Most people don't realize it but with the pixel chosen in the upper left, you simply iterate the arrays right to left top to bottom and you never need the data of the current pixel again and thus don't corrupt it. In a 3x3 kernel it shifts by -1,-1 rather than 0,0 but sometimes due to speed or memory concerns it's actually desired.

Comment: @Tatarize: in most real world use cases the shift is problematic, but there might be odd cases where you can use this optimisation.

Comment: If you are doing two in a row, you can do a flip of it iterating the other direction and getting it back to 0,0. Though, iterating in reverse you might get a bunch of cache misses. But, generally you'd do this in cases where allocating the new memory is more troublesome than shift. Or where the shift is irrelevant, (I've found a lot of cases where that's true). Or if you're set to cut off the garbage at the edge anyway.

Comment: Usually if you're cutting off the edge nonsense anyway, you fully corrupted the upper and left edge, but you can subtract two from the stride and height and have all the valid data without even redefining anything about the bitmap. -- The bigger problem is it doesn't help with GPU optimizations and those are common. So unless you're applying a convolution to an image so huge you have to read it in segments from a disk, sending it to the GPU is better.

Comment: What is pixel shift?

Comment: @Thunder: 0.5 pixel shift means that the whole image is shifted by half a pixel in both the X and Y axes.

Comment: Thanks for answer Paul. I'm very new can you pls tell does the pixel shifts happens in odd sized kernel also? And the reason for it is the dropped pixel( for "valid" type padding) and unsymmetry padding in "same" type of padding?

Comment: @Thunder: the implicit shift only occurs with even-sized kernels, due to asymmetry. This is why most filters you will encounter in image processing tend to have odd-sized kernels. An exception to this is when you want to actually implement a sub-pixel shift (interpolation for image registration) when you will typically use an odd-sized kernel but with the symmetry of the coefficients being “skewed” to achieve the sub-pixel shift.

Comment: @PaulR thanks for the answer.  Just a last one, can you suggest to me any good source where I can read up on pixel-shift in details. I tried googling it, but couldn't find a proper doc there.

Comment: @Thunder: I would start with any decent undergraduate-level introductory textbook on image processing, which will give you a good grounding on the basics of 2D filters, etc. It’s a long time since I learned all this stuff so I can’t really give any specific up-to-date references, I’m afraid.